# and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers Error

Tags: natbib

I am trying to use an unsrt format, which includes squares and numbers. I used the following codes, but each time I face either this error or [author, year] format. Could you please help me?

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

%% For including figures, graphicx.sty has been loaded in
%% elsarticle.cls. If you prefer to use the old commands
 \usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{x color}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
%\usepackage[round, sort, compress, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square, comma, numbers,sort&compress, super}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

%% The amsthm package provides extended theorem environments
%% \usepackage{amsthm}

%% The lineno packages adds line numbers. Start line numbering with
%% \begin{linenumbers}, end it with \end{linenumbers}. Or switch it on
%% for the whole article with \linenumbers.
\usepackage{lineno}

\journal{Applied Energy}

\begin{document}



\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{articleref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe not related to the problem, but don't load the same package more than once, and don't load packages at all unless you actually *need* them. Note that `epsfig` has been deprecated for more than 1/4 century.

Comment: Additionally, remember that with a few exceptions, `hyperref` needs to be the last package loaded. Also, you don't provide sample bibtex data so hard to test.

Comment: The `unsrt` style is not compatible with `natbib`, use `unsrtnat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of please clean up your preamble, and use only the packages that you actually need. As a beginner it might be a good idea to write a short comment above each package explaining what this does pr why you need it. Several packages are even loaded multiple times.

`mathpazo` and `newtxtext,newtxmath` should probably not be loaded in the same document. I'd use `enumitem` not `enumerate`. The color package is called `xcolor` not `x color`.

You are loading several packages that should not be used anymore, including `epsfig` and `fancyheadings`

With a few exceptions `hyperref` should always be the last package to be loaded.

Back to your actual problem: The BibTeX style `unsrt` is not compatible with `natbib` and does not provide data in the format that `natbib` expects, hence the error.

Instead use `unsrtnat`

Comment: Thank you so much. With your help, I no longer get that error, but the references are still in an author-year format not in number one. I tried plainnat and acmnat syle as well but the result was the same.

Comment: @baran please then create a new question and this time make a full minimal example that others have a chance to test. Plus be specific in your description of what you expected, and what you got instead